# Multiple POST request eats RES memory (htop)

Tags: java, ubuntu, memory, rabbitmq, httpurlconnection

I'll try to be brief and simple. I have a program that does:

1. Consumes JSON string messages from a RabbitMQ server.
2. Extracts important fields and puts them into another JSON (different structure). I'm using the POJO model from Jackson's parser.
3. Sends them to a server through a HTTP POST request. Using HttpUrlConnection (one connection per message) and DataOutputStream#write(byte[]).

I have 3 consumers (3 threads, each one consuming a different queue) performing these 3 steps and it works fine. However, I have a very high volume of received messages (500 messages in one hour) and it seems that the requests are eating the resident memory slowly but progressively. The heap is stable and its cleaned regularly by the garbage collector.

The problem may be at:

1. My RabbitMQ consumers: they are limited to 1 message (qos=1) till it's acknowledged so I don't think the problem is here.
2. The HttpURLConnection object: I think this is the problem because if we only consume the data the memory is stable.

With a profiler I can see that the heap grows till it reaches a peak and then the garbage collector cleans it (see the attached image):

[image]

**How can I control the resident memory used? Is there anything I can do to control massive POST requests?**

Comment: How about maintaining a pool of `HttpURLConnection`'s rather than creating a new one for each message? It's not really a resource leak, as GC is able to reclaim all mem used by the connections, it's just less-than-optimal design...

Comment: Well, I didn't pool them because of this: "Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instances. Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.". Is that right? Maybe I'm misunderstanding it.